# Python: Trying to loggin with requests and perform a HTTP request

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to loggin to my account using the following python code without success. The login-process is in two steps on two pages. First enter login, second enter password. I am using Python3:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml.html

with requests.Session() as s:
  #First login page
    login = s.get('https://accounts.ft.com/login')
    login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
#getting the form inputs
    hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input')
    form = {x.name: x.value for x in hidden_inputs}
#filling inputs with email
    form['email'] = 'me@mail.com'
    response = s.post('https://accounts.ft.com/login', data=form)
# Receive reponse 200

#Second login page
    login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)
#getting inputs
    hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input')
    form = {x.name: x.value for x in hidden_inputs}
#filling inputs with email and password
    form['email'] = 'me@mail.com'
    form['password'] = 'p****word'
    response = s.post('https://accounts.ft.com/login', data=form)
#Receive reponse 200

#Trying to read an article being loggedIn
    page = s.get('https://www.ft.com/content/173695cc-1a98-11e7-a266-12672483791a')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
# data-next-is-logged-in="false" => Please Register to read this page...
```

- Here is what the Form looks like:

```html
<div class="js-container" data-component="two-step-login-form" id="content">
  <div class="lgn-box">
    <form action="/login/submitEmail" class="js-email-lookup-form" data-test-id="enter-email-form" method="POST" name="enter-email-form" novalidate="">
      <input name="location" type="hidden" value="" />
      <input name="continueUrl" type="hidden" value="" />
      <input name="readerId" type="hidden" value="" />
      <input name="loginUrl" type="hidden" value="/login" />
      <div class="lgn-box__title">
        <h1 class="lgn-heading--alpha">
          Sign in
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="o-forms-group">
        <label class="o-forms-label" for="email">
       Email address
      </label>
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="o-forms-text js-email" id="email" maxlength="64" name="email" required="" type="email">
        <input id="password" name="password" style="display:none" type="password">
        <label for="password">
        </label>
        </input>
        </input>
      </div>
      <div class="o-forms-group">
        <button class="o-buttons o-buttons--standout o-buttons--big" name="Next" type="submit">
       Next
      </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

- Here is what my data passed to POST looks like:

  > > form
  > >     {'password': 'p****word', 'continueUrl': '', 'loginUrl': '/login', 'email': 'me@mail.com', 'readerId': '', 'location': ''}
- The POST request returns for both 1st and 2nd loggin page a 200 response. But it seems that I am still not logged in.
- I have tried using  http://accounts.ft.com/sso/redirects?email=me@mail.com as a URL for POST request, returning a 405 Bad Request error
- I am not sure that I am actually not logged in, bud I have no idea how to monitor that.
- Is it possible that the website prevents me from logging-in if not in a web-browser?

Comment: Have you looked into using something like selenium? It's entirely possible that FT blocks automated access, (try setting a user agent in your headers)

Comment: Are there any cookies returned after sending your login request? I'm not sure how the site you are attempting to login to handles authentication, but I assume you aren't maintaining your session between requests, so the 2nd GET request you try doesn't have your authenticated session cookie in the Header.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. You were right @Allen, the second GET request was wrong, however, FT is blocking connections from outside a browser. Some javascript code has to run after every login stage and even using Qt for python doesn't go arround...

Comment: Thanks @zhqiat . That's actually the solution that finally worked for me. But it's a bit to complicated for the task I needed, so I guess I'll just give up in hoping to get the data... You can make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @ylnor anything the javascript is doing should be easy to implement in Python. I'm not familiar with FT. Maybe take a look at some packet capture with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html). Login normally using FT's website, and see how authentication works, then try running your script, identify the differences in your packet capture from your script verse how it works when logging in through the website. Hopefully that will bring to light some of the reasons why your authentication attempts do not work.

Comment: @AllenButler , I had the same issue on trying to query Facebook or Twitter from python, and it appear that using javascript from python returned error, simply due to the fact that they detect that you are not using a common browser. I did the exact same thing using a browser emulator, pretending I was using chrome with selenium and there was no error anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `selenium` to simulate the web browser as it appears that FT blocks automated access.

Alternatively you can see if a site has been archived with something like [archive.is](http://archive.is) (which will pull most sites into a more machine friendly setup).

Finally, there is both a datamining API and a headline API that the FT offers at their [developer page](https://developer.ft.com/)